# Highlight color in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, editor

```
Public Sub textcolorchanged()
    Dim searchword As String = RichTextBox2.Text.ToString.Trim

    Dim index1 As Integer = 0

    While index1 <> -1
      If (index1 < ORGFILETXT.Text.Length) Then
        index1 = ORGFILETXT.Find(searchword, index1, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        'If (index1 <= ORGFILETXT.TextLength) Then
            If index1 <> -1 Then
                ORGFILETXT.SelectionStart = index1
                ORGFILETXT.SelectionLength = searchword.Length
                ORGFILETXT.SelectionColor = Color.Red
                index1 = index1 + searchword.Length
            End If
        'End If

      Else
          index1 = -1
      End if
    End While
End Sub
```

I searched word of datagridview1 rows and highlighted search word in rich text-box. text(it is having total text)
I called this method in datagridview1 mouse click and key-up and key down event

word is highlighted in rich text-box.text when I mouse click and key up and key down on datagridview1 rows of search word but some time getting full text is changed color how???
pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation of `RichTextBox.Find Method (String, Int32, RichTextBoxFinds)` I have the suspect that, if the string is not found the return value is negative, but not -1.
If this is the case then it's possible that your code fails in setting the selection color.

You could try to change this line

```
If index1 <> -1 Then
```

with

```
If index1 >= 0 Then
```

See also the their [example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9be0980x)